# Is there a masonry filler tough enough to drill into once it's set

Tags: repair, masonry, gates, hole-repair

Our new home has two old metal gates front and back where the screws mounting the locking points have chipped out of the brickwork leaving large holes (40 - 50mm tall/deep).

Is there a masonry filler tough enough that it will allow me to repair the damaged brick work and redrill the mounting points afterwards?

Comment: Might be simpler to use a frame to hold the screws in location while the masonry filler is setting. Why drill when you can pre-install the screws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clean the holes out well with vinegar and water.  then put epoxy dough in the gaps, smooth and point as well as you can.  once cured, drill new holes, but larger diameter and deeper.  then use anchoring epoxy (like redhead a7 or c6) to mount threaded rods.  attach your gates with nuts and washers and you are done.